# Consulta e inserción de datos desde PHP ¿Cual es el error?

Tags: php

Hola amigos php me marca un error pero miro la consola y no me lo muestra, acaso será porque no es posible hacer primero una consulta y después insertar esos resultados? Por favor me podrían ayudar a identificar mi problema que estoy haciendo mal y que es lo que debería hacer. Si es posible un ejemplo de cómo realizar estas dos acciones, gracias.

Mi código ajax:

```
function Obtener_Resultados(){


    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "Resultados/obtener_resultados_preliminares.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{id_alumno: id_estudiante},
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonp:"jsoncallback",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false
    });

     request.done(function(data){
        if(data.estado=="exito"){


            alert("Exito");

        }else{
            alert("Error: No se pudieron obtener los resultados");

        }
    });

    request.fail(function(textStatus){
        alert("Error en la petición: obtencion de resultados: " +  JSON.stringify(textStatus));
    });

}
```

Mi código PHP, en dode estoy intentando insertar los 9 resultados del select:

```
<?php

  header("Content-Type: text/json");

    $id_estudiante = $_GET['id_alumno'];

    $datos = array();
    $array_resultados = array();
    $array_perfiles = array();



    $sql = "";

    $perfiles =9;

    include_once('../../Verificacion/Conexion/Abrir_Conexion.php');

    for($i=1; $i <= $perfiles; $i++){

        $sql .= "SELECT sum(res.respuesta) FROM respuestas as res INNER JOIN preguntas as pre ON res.id_pregunta = pre.id_pregunta WHERE res.id_alumno = '$id_estudiante' AND pre.id_pregunta IN (select id_pregunta from preguntas where id_perfil='$i') group by res.id_alumno;";
    }


    if($conexion->multi_query($sql) === true ){

        do {

             if ($result = $conexion->store_result()) {
                 while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    array_push($array_resultados, $row[0]);
                    //var_dump($row[0]);
                 }
                 $result->free();
             }
         } while ($conexion->next_result());
         //var_dump($array_resultados);
         //$datos["estado"] = "exito";

    }else{
        printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
        $datos["estado"] = "error";
    }


    $id_perfil= 1;
    $sql2 = "";

    for($i=0; $i < 9; $i++){

        $resultado = $array_resultados[$i];
        $sql2 .= "INSERT INTO puntajes (resultado, id_alumno, id_perfil) VALUES ('$resultado', '$id_estudiante', '$id_perfil');";
        $id_perfil++;
    }

    if($conexion->multi_query($sql2) === true){


        $datos["estado"] = "exito";

    }else{
        printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
        $datos["estado"] = "error";
    }

    include_once('../../Verificacion/Conexion/Cerrar_Conexion.php');



    $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
    //var_dump($resultadoJson);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';

?>
```

Solo me muestra esto:

> jQuery33101339963985367767_1533999913622({"estado":"exito"});

También al parecer volví a realizar otra prueba pero sigue siendo el mismo código no modifique nada y me mostró ahora esto:

> jQuery33105952178305361888_1534001036055([]);

Ya me di cuenta que si los inserta los 9 resultados pero al parecer me inserta otros de más, solo deben ser 9 y no 18. Ya que se vuelven a repetir los 'id' 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 y otra ves 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Que esta pasando y aclaro que la primera columna 'resultado de la imagen siempre se repiten los primeros 9 números en todos los intentos' es decir: 2,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Errores al cambiar $_GET['id_alumno'];  por  $_POST['id_alumno']; en mi php.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

viendo el codigo, el error es que envias la peticion por ajax con metodo `POST` y en el `PHP` lo capturas con metodo `GET`  por ende, la varaible `$id_estudiant` siempre estara vacia y la consulta

```
$sql .= "SELECT sum(res.respuesta) FROM respuestas as res INNER JOIN preguntas as pre ON res.id_pregunta = pre.id_pregunta WHERE res.id_alumno = '$id_estudiante' AND pre.id_pregunta IN (select id_pregunta from preguntas where id_perfil='$i') group by res.id_alumno;";
```

siempre sera nula

corrigue esto:

```
$id_estudiante = $_GET['id_alumno'];
```

por esto:

```
$id_estudiante = $_POST['id_alumno'];
```

espero te sirva y la marques xD... **ReNiceCode...**

Comment: No funciono amigo, e incluso me salieron más errores. Gracias por intentarlo.

Comment: que errores te salieron ? tambien note que tiene un error de ciclos con el DoWhile, ya que se ejecuta una vez y luego pregunta, como si tiene vuelve a ejecutar y vuelve a preguntar, a la segunda ya no tiene, pero se ha ejecutado dos veces

Comment: ¿Qué errores adicionales salieron? Al enviar por POST de deben capturar los datos como Post.

Comment: mirar la captura arriba y veras.

Comment: @DiegosSánchez, lo siento, pero no se por que tengro problemas al ver imagenes, asi, que si deseas, copia y pega el error y sigo en el intento

Comment: amigo lo puedes ver la imagen haciendo Zoom que trae el navegador arriba a la esquina derecha.

Comment: @DiegosSánchez, no bro me aparece que no puede cargar la pagina, es un error extraño, como ya te dije no puedo, verlas siquiera